# How To Get HTTPS for dotnet Local Development

Tags: asp.net-web-api, .net-core, https

I have been running a dotnet webapi project. I just changed my machine. On my old laptop HTTPS was working fine in my local development. But now that I have changed my machine my browser does not trust the localhost server certificate. I have tried running `dotnet dev-certs https --trust` but it did not work. My old and my new machine are running on Windows. Any help?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#troubleshoot-certificate-problems). There are a multitude of probable causes and you've not really provided any more information to go on, but this page includes most of the issues with the dotnet dev-certificates.

Comment: Thanks, by running dotnet dev-certs https --clean and
dotnet dev-certs https --trust, respectively, it got sorted.